# In Plug.Router what is the point of the init function?

Tags: elixir

Trying to get an understanding on Plug, specifically Plug.Router. From the documentation (http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Router.html). From the specification plugs have an init function that is called at initalization time to pass in options, but those don't seem to be available in the defined routes.

What is the reason for not having options available and is there a pattern that would allow it to be?

Answer (score 12):

Heres an excerpt from the book - Programming Phoenix:

"Sometimes, you might need Phoenix to do some heavy lifting to transform options. That’s the job of the init function. **init happens at compile time**. Plug will use the result of init as the second argument to call. Because init is often called at compilation time, it is the perfect place to validate options and prepare some of the work. That way, call can be as fast as possible. Since call is the workhorse, we want it to do as little work as possible. "

For example - Using a plug in your routes.ex file

```
  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
    plug Example.Authenticated, repo: Example.Repo
  end
```

`repo: Example.Repo` is the options being passed - to the `init` function inside Example.Repo

```
defmodule Example.Authenticated do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts) do 
   Keyword.fetch!(opts, :repo)
  end

  def call(conn, repo) do
   ...
  end

end
```

I'm assuming in the case of Plug.Router - at compile time modifications could be - loading modules that build/modify routes - possibly from an external source?  Depends on what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: This should be the answer. I'm a new user to Phoenix and Plug, and the compile-time aspect is not obvious from the online docs. I couldn't figure out why a simple test logging function wasn't getting hit, but since it's at compile time this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The work of the init function is mainly to make options be available at compile time.This options is then passed to call function as the second argument.

To my opinion i think you can decide to have options or not depending on the task the plug function or module is meant to accomplish .